# Printing matrix values

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

I don't understand something about my program. Here's the code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>

    int main(){

    int t[2][5], i, j;

    t[1][0]=2;
    t[1][1]=3;
    t[1][2]=4;
    t[1][3]=5;
    t[1][4]=6;

    t[0][2]=7;
    t[1][2]=8;

    for(i=0; i<2; i++){
        for(j=0; j<5; j++){
            printf("%d ", t[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for(i=0; i<2; i++){
        t[0][i]=0;
    }

    for(i=0; i<2; i++){
        for(j=0; j<5; j++){
            printf("%d ", t[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


return 0;
}
```

It gives me this output:

```
0 0 7 0 4196128 
2 3 8 5 6 
0 0 7 0 4196128 
2 3 8 5 6
```

I don't understand why that 4196128 pops up. Please explain.

I suppose it has something to do with the compiler.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal Why is t[0][0] = 0? I didn't initialize t[0][0] either.

Comment: You did. `for(i=0; i<2; i++){t[0][i]=0;}` will do that.

Comment: @TimRandall I did that after tho.

Comment: Well, if you're not clear about whether you're talking about the first printout or the second, then our communication is going to be ambiguous and prone to misunderstandings. I understood "I didn't initialize t[0][0]" to mean that you thought you had _never_ assigned a value. That's why I pointed out that you did.

Comment: Here is the program in its minimum verifiable form: `int main(){ int t; printf("%d ", t); }`

Comment: Keep this in mind: it is **never the compiler**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's related to the unitialized values and their usage.

For the array `t[0]`, you never initialized any element other than `t[0][2]`. So, the value of the other elements remains "indeterminate".

Now, the elements

- have a type which can have trap representation
- never have their address taken

So, attempt to use the value of any element which has indeterminate value would be [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: actually `t[0][0]` and `t[0][1]` were set to zero before the second printout. The array indexing used the "wrong" variable, which makes that difficult to spot.

Comment: @TimRandall, true, but once your program invoke UB, no guarantee whatsoever.

Comment: I don't think printing the values of integers is as dangerous as you are implying.

Comment: @TimRandall using unitialized values of any kind is a source of big bad bugs even if not dangerous. I'd hypothesize that integers are even worse than anything else since they may be less obvious to spot (imagine having a garbage value of 5 instead of say intended 100 which is not too difficult to happen given memory layout and usage).

Answer (score 0):

You never assigned a value to several elements in your array. When you print them out, you're getting to see what was in the memory beforehand.
Specifically:
At the time of the first printout, t[0][0] t[0][1] t[0][3] t[0][4] are uninitialized.
At the time of the second printout, t[0][3] t[0][4] are uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

The value 4196128 is printed when accessing the value at `t[0][4]`. That location in `t` is not set, so you read a value that isn't initialized, and will be whatever was in the memory before, or whatever the compiler wants it to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `{0}` solve your problem.

```
int t[2][5]={0}
```

all numbers that you do not modify will print '0'

**`OUTPUT:`**

```
0 0 7 0 0
2 3 8 5 6
0 0 7 0 0
2 3 8 5 6
```

When we initialize a variable it will have a random number.
Ex: `int x`

If you print the `x` you will see a random number like 5346

So you don't need this piece of code:

```
for(i=0; i<2; i++){
        t[0][i]=0;
    }
```

Just put the `{0}`